# Good web based download manager?

Tags: php, web-applications

I already asked this question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446624/good-web-based-download-manager), but since I couldn't find exaclty what I was looking for (and based on Workshop Alex suggestion in the answer) I decide to ask here.

Here in our company we usually make avaiable some files to our costumers and partners. There's an administrative interface where we upload a file (an ISO, a pdf manual, etc), referencing it to a Product in the company. Then, we set permissions to that file to the users that would "see" that file.

When the user logins to the system, he sees a listing of Products and files he has access.

We already have a small php utility that has this functionality, but it's old, difficult to maintain and full of problems. We don't see fixing it as an option: we would create one from scratch a or use an already robust solution. What I'm looking for is an open source solution that could achieve what I described instead of rewriting it. Other features I would like implemented:

- Written in php (preferred, but other scripting languages are welcome)
- Capability of users and groups of users, with login and password;
- Upload and delete files in filesystem from the web based interface;
- Set permission in uploaded files or in group of files based in users or group of users;
- Listing of files;
- Relatively easy to adapt templates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have used the [Boxroom](http://boxroom.rubyforge.org/) project (written in Ruby on Rails) as a simple way to serve files to certain groups with certain permissions.  Sounds like it meets all your criteria.  My old employer even sponsored the author to add virtual hosting.

It was somewhat abandoned by its author but it sounds like it has since been re-adopted (twice).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason this needs to be web-based? It sounds like an FTP server/client setup would provide all the features you need.

Comment: People are used to this setup. It's a friendly approach too. I'm trying to keep it similar. If I can't find a good web based solution, a FTP would be an option. I'm going yo analyze whats the "best of both worlds".

Answer (score -1):

Check out CrushFTP. We LOVE it.